# OpenCL - improve memory size usage

Tags: 2d, opencl, dimensions, large-data

I'm now working on a project with GPUs that gave me slower results than CPU.
The reason is that I'm enqueuing a too small data array as input ( Length = 1024 )

I would like to enqueue more data but I'm stuck because of the memory usage.
I'm computing inside my kernel 283 functions, each evaluated on 481 periods.

So in order to get back my results I had to create an array that sizes N(here 1024) x 481 x 283 of doubles (because the 283 functions return double value)

This length is too large. As I want to put more data, the ouput will be 481 x 283 larger and I will reach the GPU's memory limit. I don't know how to use less memory.

This is an example of my kernel function:

PERIODS = 481
data = input at get_global_id(0)
OUTPUT(get_global_id(0), t, x) is the accessor to store the results ( tri-dimensionnal array)

> for(int t=0; t < PERIODS; t++)
>   OUTPUT(get_global_id(0), t, 1) = function1(data, t);
>   for(int t=0; t < PERIODS; t++)
>       OUTPUT(get_global_id(0), t, 2) = function2(data, t);
>   for(int t=0; t < PERIODS; t++)
>       OUTPUT(get_global_id(0), t, 3) = function3(data, t);

Of course it looks bad but the problem is that my "called" functions sometimes need the value at T=12 or T=24. So I have to compute all periods for each function to be sure the value they need are present inside OUTPUT accessor.

For example : In a 2D problem( data, PERIODS) -- function2 needs the result of function1 at T=4. But work-items are not all synchronized. So maybe the value function2 needs is there, maybe not. The solution was to ensure that by putting for loops around all functions called and going from 2D problem to 1D ( It looks realllly bad, a 2D organization could have been great.. but I didn't find any ways to sync all threads through global memory)

The first idea I had to use less memory is to call 481 times the kernel function with an argument T = t. So the output array will weigh 481 less than now and I could put 481 more data. But to use this solution I have to factorize my for loops which is not really possible I guess. ( Like I said : Because the function2 could need the function1 result at T = 4 for example )

If you have any ideas or solutions, I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: For what you describe looks like your problem is not well suited for SIMD. You have a bunch of functions with multiple ifs inside (otherwise you wouldn't need different data). The execution will be horribly slow. You have to convert your problem into something you can run in all the threads at the same time without branches.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Branches are the worst thing I've read about GPU usage. I can't really prevent them .. You could be right

But I had an idea at the moment I'm writting.  What if I'm converting all of my 283 functions into 283 different kernels ?

From Host I could do : enqueue a kernel, read back data, enqueue the next kernel, read back data 
In order to construct my tri-dimensionnal output but on the Host side

With this idea I could inject 283 more inputs because the ouput weighs 283 less.

Comment: 283 different kernels, running one after another with size 1 and having CPU dependancy, it will be even worse. You need to change the algorithm.

Comment: Not really with size 1. But with size N=1024 in the example I introduced.
Now if I'm running a single kernel that call 283 functions, I need an output array that sizes N*481*283. So we are close to 1GB of GPU memory usage. But If Im doing 283 kernels : the output array will size N*481. So we can use more memory, thus more input data like N = 289792

Comment: Well that may work, but try not to have any CPU dependancy, so you don need to stop the GPU execution waiting for the CPU to decide. Queue all the element at once (the 283 kernels). Anyway with just 1024 as size it is quite small amount of work to do...

Comment: If memory weren't a problem, how large of a dataset could you supply? Length= 1M, 10M...?

Comment: close to 1 million at this moment

Answer (score 0):

> I'm now working on a project with GPUs that gave me slower results
>   than CPU. The reason is that I'm enqueuing a too small data array as
>   input ( Length = 1024 )

Assuming your gpu has asynchronoys dma modules, why don't you implement it as pipelined? Upload 1st iteration, compute 1st while uploading 2nd, download 1st while computing 2nd also uploading 3rd, download 2 + compute 3 + upload 4, download 3 + compute 4 + upload 5. This should hide at least reads or writes to gpu.

> I would like to enqueue more data but I'm stuck because of the memory
>   usage. I'm computing inside my kernel 283 functions, each evaluated on
>   481 periods.
>
> So in order to get back my results I had to create an array that sizes
>   N(here 1024) x 481 x 283 of doubles (because the 283 functions return
>   double value)

Assuming recursivity of "function" doesn't span over GB, you could enqueue each request of type

```
OUTPUT[thread_num], period_num, f_num) = function_f_num(data, period_num);
```

into a list when you only need it(instead of computing everything). Then, when queue reaches about 1M elements, upload it to gpu. Add fake recursivity (using multiply-copied kernel names with post-fix or some semi-stack structure backing a kernel) to find any elements that needs recursivity. Instead of recursivity, uncomputable elements could be added into a new list, having recursivity in host-side to complete all sub-lists. This should also give software an explicit multi gpu usage advantage since you can compute multiple queues in different gpus. Or, you could simply use host pointer by gpu to use all host-side buffers. Have a look at **CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR** parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I'm working on code that sizes 8000 lines in opencl with a lot of function calls. My kernel was about 1,1 MB and sometimes I had bug because of this too large size. That's why I had to use the OUTPUT array as large as it needs. Now when function2 need the function1 result, it doesn't need to call function1 because the kernel size will be too large, but it could just check the result in OUTPUT array caculated before function2 call.

Comment: I used 

d_output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR , Sizeof.cl_double * MODELPOINTS_LENGTH * (T_MAX+1) * NBR_FX_MAX, Pointer.to(h_output), null);

But when I enqueue the kernel, the memory usage is going to reach the size : N * T_MAX * NBR_FX * sizeof(double) bytes. Why the device doesn't use the pointer but needs all the data copied ? 

Like you said I would like the device to use the pointer rather than copy all data

Comment: Maybe drivers are bugged?

Comment: After checking where the memory usage grows up : It happens when I set the device pointer to kernel's argument and then use clEnqueueNDRangeKernel function from host code. If I'm not setting this pointer as a kernel argument, the memory doesn't grow up

I will check if it's a driver problem. But to clarify : When using CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR it doesn't allocate memory on the device ? Maybe I'm wrong with this concept

Comment: You create a buffer but it shouldn't create an exact copy, it would be against the usage of it. "OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer contents pointed to by host_ptr in device memory. This cached copy can be used when kernels are executed on a device." says khronos.

Comment: The buffer created on the device side will have the same size as host one ?
Heum for example. If I'm creating an array of 10000 doubles on host code then using  clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double) * 100000, myHostArray); 

Will it takes as much memory on device side ? If so I don't understand the usage of  CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR.

(Thank for your time and your comments).

Comment: "Implementation defined" says khronos so it may overflow and spill to main memory instead of giving error since its driver side caching.